# WebBrowser - show a simple string message without navigating away

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser (System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser) that opens at certain time and displays nothing.  It is just white page.
I'd like to display a simple message "Waiting" in that form without redirecting anywhere else. This WebBrowser is part of a WPF xaml form.

I have tried to do this in WebBrowser_Loaded event below but that calls OnNavigate() again which is what I dont want to do.  I just need to get simple string message like "Waiting" in it, that is all.

```
private void WebBrowser_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((WebBrowser)sender).NavigateToString("<html><body><h1>Waiting</h1></body></html>"); // this will try to navigate to new page which is what I do not want to do
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the .NET WebBrowser control to be really finicky and somewhat hard to deal with.  I would suggest doing something like this:

Put a TextBox or Label control on top of the WebBrowser control with the "Waiting..." text in it, and hide that control in the Navigating (or Navigated) event for the WebBrowser.

Comment: It feels hacky, but sometimes hacky is better than nothing.  =)